# Google youtube API, how do i search for specific keyword?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to search for keyword related youtube videos, I'm using youtube getdata API.

Reading documentation I came up with this:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/". urlencode($kwd) ."?orderby=viewCount&max-results=". $max ."&alt=json
```

But this is not a real search, it gives urls taged with keyword... Youtubes internal search works quite differently I imagine, because comparing results don't match at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL you offer does a search for any videos in a category where the category includes your keyword. What you want to do instead is to send a query string:

```
"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=". urlencode($kwd) ."&orderby=viewCount&max-results=". $max ."&alt=json"
```

This way the feed will match right on the videos rather than the categories.

In the newer v3 of the API, your call would look like:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=".urlencode($kwd)."&maxResults=".$max."&order=viewCount&key={YOUR_API_KEY}"
```

Comment: Yes, figured it out. Can you please comment what is benefit of using v3? Is json data returned same or similar so I don't have to rewrite iterator?

Comment: Several benefits: 1) It is JSON from the get-go (no need to specify an alternate serialization), 2) They are standardizing endpoints and object schemas as much as possible so you don't have to deal with the headaches that the different feed forms take, and 3) v3 is the direction they're going internally, so eventually v2 will be deprecated and disappear. Having said that, the json itself is quite a bit different so it would take some work in rewriting your iterator. Short term work for long term benefits, I guess!

Answer (score 1):

Use Data API v3, [search->list method](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=term&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: Does it work with Android API Key? (a key restricted for android apps)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I would use the "q" parameter, for example to search for "dog"

var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        q: "dog"
    });

But I'm just a noob the others guys answers are probably better.