# How can I scrape videos from a YouTube search?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to search for a specific keyword and then scrape all the videos URLs.

I know the code I am about to paste is not going to do that, but I want to show what I have done.

```
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?sp=CAISAggBUBQ%253D&q=minecraft")

links = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('/watch')
for link in links:
    links = (links.get_attribute("href"))
```

How can I scrape the links and save them to a file?

Comment: look in id `item-section-897216` and all the links will be there

Comment: Can you consider updating your Question with your exact manual steps which you are trying to Automate? Within this "https://www.youtube.com/results?sp=CAISAggBUBQ%253D&q=minecraft" URL I am unable to find any `partial_link_text` with `linkText` set to `/watch`.  I only found `Watch later`. But I don't think thats what you are looking for. Thanks

Comment: You'd probably be better off in the long run by using their excellent API. Much faster that using selenium and so on. Lots of posts on SO on how to do that. Check out this one for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20125750/8240959

Answer (score 2):

Here is your code Gives you the title and the url of the video 
Light and Easy :)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request


def SearchVid(search):
    responce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='+search)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(responce)    
    divs = soup.find_all("div", { "class" : "yt-lockup-content"})


    for i in divs:
        href= i.find('a', href=True)
        print(href.text,  "\nhttps://www.youtube.com"+href['href'], '\n')
        with open(SearchString.replace("%20", "_")+'.txt', 'a') as writer:
            writer.write("https://www.youtube.com"+href['href']+'\n')

print("What are you looking for?")
SearchString = input()
SearchVid(SearchString.replace(" ", "%20"))
```

Comment: Hello, I find this is not working anymore. I am not a coder. Do you know how I can solve/update it?

Comment: @MateoCriado I imagine the reason this no longer works, if your error is incomplete results, is because the search results page autoloads more results at the bottom when the user scrolls.

Comment: I will debug it later tonight

Answer (score 0):

This script pulls the results from the first page of YouTube results using `urllib`, and prints all the links of the videos by parsing the page using `BeautifulSoup`(if you are using python 3.* then install `BeautifulSoup4`).

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

textToSearch = 'python tutorials'
query = urllib.parse.quote(textToSearch)
url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + query
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for vid in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'yt-uix-tile-link'}):
    if not vid['href'].startswith("https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/"):
        print('https://www.youtube.com' + vid['href'])
```

Answer (score -3):

Actually, you should not scrape result from youtube.com/results. you have to check robots.txt first before scraping any website.
to know more about robots.txt please read this wiki page.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

here is youtube's robots.txt file.

https://www.youtube.com/robots.txt

you have another option though, you can use youtube search API.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Comment: Given that google is known not to respect robots.txt, faking user-agent of their crawlers etc etc, I would say that it's morally justified that you don't respect their robots.txt.

Comment: Name checks out.